# Detecting blades of a wind turbine

Tags: edge-detection, image-registration, background-subtraction, stitching

I have many close-range images of a single wind turbine blade (taken from different positions, same angle):

[image]

I need to separate the blade image from background like this:

[image]

The problem arises in image alignment application where the blade image moves about large amount while the background does not (parallax effect). The backgroud also consists of more pixels so it is prefered for alignment while the blade is discarded.

Another problem is that the blade surface is very smooth and there are few to none interest points to detect.

Is it for example possible to detect one or more curves to isolate boundary of the blades and then possibly align the curves instead of interest points?

Another approach would be to use graph cut to extract the precise edge and convert it to spline curve - however, how to align such curves? Maybe 3D surfaces based on intensity data can be aligned rather than 2D curves.

Any more ideas?